# \titlecontents* and the hyperref bug

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, titletoc

I'm having really hard time with a custom Table of Contents with [`titletoc`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/titletoc): wrong links with [`hyperref`](https://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) package because of a bug (this [has already been noted by Bezos](https://github.com/latex3/hyperref/issues/86), creator of `titletoc`).

Given the simple following code:

```
\documentclass{book}

    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \usepackage{titletoc}
    \usepackage{hyperref}

    \titlecontents{chapter}%
        [0em]% left
        {\bigskip}% above
        {\bf\large\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel.]{2em}\hspace{0em}}%
        {\hspace*{-2em}}%
        {\hfill\bf\contentspage}%
        [\smallskip]%
    % 
    \titlecontents{section}%
        [1.5em]%
        {\small\contentsmargin{1.5em}}%
        {\bf\thecontentslabel\hspace{7pt}}%
        {\hspace*{-2em}}%
        {\enspace\titlerule*[0.5pc]{.}~\contentspage}%
    %
    \titlecontents*{subsection}%
        [3em]%
        {\footnotesize\contentsmargin{0em}}%
        {\thecontentslabel\space}%
        {}%
        {}%
        [ -- ]%

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \chapter{Title}
    \lipsum
        \section{Title}
            \subsection{Title}
            \subsection{Title}
            \subsection{Title}
            \lipsum
            \subsection{Title}
            \subsection{Title}
            \lipsum
    \chapter{Title}
    \chapter{Title}
\end{document}
```

one can suddenly notice (see figure below) that the hyperlink to 'Chapter 2' points to 'Subsection 1.1', which is really annoying.

[image]

I've searched long around tex.SE but solutions to the same problem do not cure the pathology with **this layout** which I need to maintain. 
I'm also surprised since the only difference in the starred version seems to be the spacing in number of paragraphs

```
\newcommand\titlecontents{%
  \@ifstar{\ttl@contents{\z@}}% \z@ = zero paragraph?
          {\ttl@contents{\@ne}}}% \@ne = zero paragraph?
```

but I could not go further since nesting dolls-like function get definition and the code unaccessible.
Finally I noted that the problem is just given by the very first chapter following a subsection (it does not happen between subsections, subsections and sections nor between sections and chapters nor between chapters and chapters, then if one could add a *real* `\phantomsection`, that is it does not shows in the TOC.

## EDIT: Log_FILE

> ```
> This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2019.12.14)  14 DEC 2019 16:42
> entering extended mode
>  \write18 enabled.
>  file:line:error style messages enabled.
>  %&-line parsing enabled.
> **Untitled.tex
> (./Untitled.tex
> LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>
> (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/book.cls
> Document Class: book 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX document class
> (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/bk10.clo
> File: bk10.clo 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX file (size option)
> )
> \c@part=\count80
> \c@chapter=\count81
> \c@section=\count82
> \c@subsection=\count83
> \c@subsubsection=\count84
> \c@paragraph=\count85
> \c@subparagraph=\count86
> \c@figure=\count87
> \c@table=\count88
> \abovecaptionskip=\skip41
> \belowcaptionskip=\skip42
> \bibindent=\dimen102
> )
> (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lipsum/lipsum.sty
> (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
> Package: expl3 2019-05-07 L3 programming layer (loader) 
>
> (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3-code.tex
> Package: expl3 2019-05-07 L3 programming layer (code)
> \c_max_int=\count89
> \l_tmpa_int=\count90
> \l_tmpb_int=\count91
> \g_tmpa_int=\count92
> \g_tmpb_int=\count93
> \g__kernel_prg_map_int=\count94
> \c__ior_term_ior=\count95
> \c_log_iow=\count96
> \l_iow_line_count_int=\count97
> \l__iow_line_target_int=\count98
> \l__iow_one_indent_int=\count99
> \l__iow_indent_int=\count100
> \c_zero_dim=\dimen103
> \c_max_dim=\dimen104
> \l_tmpa_dim=\dimen105
> \l_tmpb_dim=\dimen106
> \g_tmpa_dim=\dimen107
> \g_tmpb_dim=\dimen108
> \c_zero_skip=\skip43
> \c_max_skip=\skip44
> \l_tmpa_skip=\skip45
> \l_tmpb_skip=\skip46
> \g_tmpa_skip=\skip47
> \g_tmpb_skip=\skip48
> \c_zero_muskip=\muskip10
> \c_max_muskip=\muskip11
> \l_tmpa_muskip=\muskip12
> \l_tmpb_muskip=\muskip13
> \g_tmpa_muskip=\muskip14
> \g_tmpb_muskip=\muskip15
> \l_keys_choice_int=\count101
> \l__intarray_loop_int=\count102
> \c__intarray_sp_dim=\dimen109
> \g__intarray_font_int=\count103
> \c__fp_leading_shift_int=\count104
> \c__fp_middle_shift_int=\count105
> \c__fp_trailing_shift_int=\count106
> \c__fp_big_leading_shift_int=\count107
> \c__fp_big_middle_shift_int=\count108
> \c__fp_big_trailing_shift_int=\count109
> \c__fp_Bigg_leading_shift_int=\count110
> \c__fp_Bigg_middle_shift_int=\count111
> \c__fp_Bigg_trailing_shift_int=\count112
> \c__kernel_randint_max_int=\count113
> \g__fp_array_int=\count114
> \l__fp_array_loop_int=\count115
> \l__sort_length_int=\count116
> \l__sort_min_int=\count117
> \l__sort_top_int=\count118
> \l__sort_max_int=\count119
> \l__sort_true_max_int=\count120
> \l__sort_block_int=\count121
> \l__sort_begin_int=\count122
> \l__sort_end_int=\count123
> \l__sort_A_int=\count124
> \l__sort_B_int=\count125
> \l__sort_C_int=\count126
> \l__tl_analysis_normal_int=\count127
> \l__tl_analysis_index_int=\count128
> \l__tl_analysis_nesting_int=\count129
> \l__tl_analysis_type_int=\count130
> \l__regex_internal_a_int=\count131
> \l__regex_internal_b_int=\count132
> \l__regex_internal_c_int=\count133
> \l__regex_balance_int=\count134
> \l__regex_group_level_int=\count135
> \l__regex_mode_int=\count136
> \c__regex_cs_in_class_mode_int=\count137
> \c__regex_cs_mode_int=\count138
> \l__regex_catcodes_int=\count139
> \l__regex_default_catcodes_int=\count140
> \c__regex_catcode_D_int=\count141
> \c__regex_catcode_S_int=\count142
> \c__regex_catcode_L_int=\count143
> \c__regex_catcode_O_int=\count144
> \c__regex_catcode_A_int=\count145
> \c__regex_all_catcodes_int=\count146
> \l__regex_show_lines_int=\count147
> \l__regex_min_state_int=\count148
> \l__regex_max_state_int=\count149
> \l__regex_left_state_int=\count150
> \l__regex_right_state_int=\count151
> \l__regex_capturing_group_int=\count152
> \l__regex_min_pos_int=\count153
> \l__regex_max_pos_int=\count154
> \l__regex_curr_pos_int=\count155
> \l__regex_start_pos_int=\count156
> \l__regex_success_pos_int=\count157
> \l__regex_curr_char_int=\count158
> \l__regex_curr_catcode_int=\count159
> \l__regex_last_char_int=\count160
> \l__regex_case_changed_char_int=\count161
> \l__regex_curr_state_int=\count162
> \l__regex_step_int=\count163
> \l__regex_min_active_int=\count164
> \l__regex_max_active_int=\count165
> \l__regex_replacement_csnames_int=\count166
> \l__regex_match_count_int=\count167
> \l__regex_min_submatch_int=\count168
> \l__regex_submatch_int=\count169
> \l__regex_zeroth_submatch_int=\count170
> \g__regex_trace_regex_int=\count171
> \c_empty_box=\box27
> \l_tmpa_box=\box28
> \l_tmpb_box=\box29
> \g_tmpa_box=\box30
> \g_tmpb_box=\box31
> \l__box_top_dim=\dimen110
> \l__box_bottom_dim=\dimen111
> \l__box_left_dim=\dimen112
> \l__box_right_dim=\dimen113
> \l__box_top_new_dim=\dimen114
> \l__box_bottom_new_dim=\dimen115
> \l__box_left_new_dim=\dimen116
> \l__box_right_new_dim=\dimen117
> \l__box_internal_box=\box32
> \l__coffin_internal_box=\box33
> \l__coffin_internal_dim=\dimen118
> \l__coffin_offset_x_dim=\dimen119
> \l__coffin_offset_y_dim=\dimen120
> \l__coffin_x_dim=\dimen121
> \l__coffin_y_dim=\dimen122
> \l__coffin_x_prime_dim=\dimen123
> \l__coffin_y_prime_dim=\dimen124
> \c_empty_coffin=\box34
> \l__coffin_aligned_coffin=\box35
> \l__coffin_aligned_internal_coffin=\box36
> \l_tmpa_coffin=\box37
> \l_tmpb_coffin=\box38
> \g_tmpa_coffin=\box39
> \g_tmpb_coffin=\box40
> \l__coffin_bounding_shift_dim=\dimen125
> \l__coffin_left_corner_dim=\dimen126
> \l__coffin_right_corner_dim=\dimen127
> \l__coffin_bottom_corner_dim=\dimen128
> \l__coffin_top_corner_dim=\dimen129
> \l__coffin_scaled_total_height_dim=\dimen130
> \l__coffin_scaled_width_dim=\dimen131
> \c__coffin_empty_coffin=\box41
> \l__coffin_display_coffin=\box42
> \l__coffin_display_coord_coffin=\box43
> \l__coffin_display_pole_coffin=\box44
> \l__coffin_display_offset_dim=\dimen132
> \l__coffin_display_x_dim=\dimen133
> \l__coffin_display_y_dim=\dimen134
> \g__file_internal_ior=\read1
> \l__seq_internal_a_int=\count172
> \l__seq_internal_b_int=\count173
> \c__deprecation_minus_one=\count174
> )
> (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3pdfmode.def
> File: l3pdfmode.def 2019-04-06 v L3 Experimental driver: PDF mode
> \l__driver_color_stack_int=\count175
> \l__driver_pdf_tmp_box=\box45
> ))
> (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
> Package: xparse 2019-05-03 L3 Experimental document command parser
> \l__xparse_current_arg_int=\count176
> \g__xparse_grabber_int=\count177
> \l__xparse_m_args_int=\count178
> \l__xparse_v_nesting_int=\count179
> )
> Package: lipsum 2019/01/02 v2.2 150 paragraphs of Lorem Ipsum dummy text
>
> (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lipsum/lipsum.ltd.tex
> File: lipsum.ltd.tex 2019/01/02 v2.2 The Lorem ipsum dummy text
> ))
> (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/titlesec/titletoc.sty
> Package: titletoc 2011/12/15 v1.6 TOC entries
> \ttl@leftsep=\dimen135
> )
> (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
> Package: hyperref 2018/11/30 v6.88e Hypertext links for LaTeX
>
> (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-hyperref.sty
> Package: hobsub-hyperref 2016/05/16 v1.14 Bundle oberdiek, subset hyperref (HO)
>
>
> (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-generic.sty
> Package: hobsub-generic 2016/05/16 v1.14 Bundle oberdiek, subset generic (HO)
> Package: hobsub 2016/05/16 v1.14 Construct package bundles (HO)
> Package: infwarerr 2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
> Package: ltxcmds 2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
> Package: ifluatex 2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
> Package ifluatex Info: LuaTeX not detected.
> Package: ifvtex 2016/05/16 v1.6 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
> Package ifvtex Info: VTeX not detected.
> Package: intcalc 2016/05/16 v1.2 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
> Package: ifpdf 2018/09/07 v3.3 Provides the ifpdf switch
> Package: etexcmds 2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
> Package: kvsetkeys 2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)
> Package: kvdefinekeys 2016/05/16 v1.4 Define keys (HO)
> Package: pdftexcmds 2018/09/10 v0.29 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
> )
> Package pdftexcmds Info: LuaTeX not detected.
> Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
> Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
> Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
> Package: pdfescape 2016/05/16 v1.14 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
> Package: bigintcalc 2016/05/16 v1.4 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO
> )
> Package: bitset 2016/05/16 v1.2 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
> Package: uniquecounter 2016/05/16 v1.3 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
> )
> Package hobsub Info: Skipping package `hobsub' (already loaded).
> Package: letltxmacro 2016/05/16 v1.5 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
> Package: hopatch 2016/05/16 v1.3 Wrapper for package hooks (HO)
> Package: xcolor-patch 2016/05/16 xcolor patch
> Package: atveryend 2016/05/16 v1.9 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
> Package atveryend Info: \enddocument detected (standard20110627).
> Package: atbegshi 2016/06/09 v1.18 At begin shipout hook (HO)
> Package: refcount 2016/05/16 v3.5 Data extraction from label references (HO)
> Package: hycolor 2016/05/16 v1.8 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
> )
> (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
> Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
> \KV@toks@=\toks14
> )
> (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty
> Package: ifxetex 2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
> )
> (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/auxhook.sty
> Package: auxhook 2016/05/16 v1.4 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
> )
> (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty
> Package: kvoptions 2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)
> )
> \@linkdim=\dimen136
> \Hy@linkcounter=\count180
> \Hy@pagecounter=\count181
>
> (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def
> File: pd1enc.def 2018/11/30 v6.88e Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
> Now handling font encoding PD1 ...
> ... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding PD1
> )
> \Hy@SavedSpaceFactor=\count182
>
> (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/hyperref.cfg
> File: hyperref.cfg 2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
> )
> Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 4519.
> Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 4524.
> Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 4527.
> Package hyperref Info: Plain pages OFF on input line 4534.
> Package hyperref Info: Backreferencing OFF on input line 4539.
> Package hyperref Info: Implicit mode ON; LaTeX internals redefined.
> Package hyperref Info: Bookmarks ON on input line 4772.
> \c@Hy@tempcnt=\count183
>
> (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty
> \Urlmuskip=\muskip16
> Package: url 2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
> )
> LaTeX Info: Redefining \url on input line 5125.
> \XeTeXLinkMargin=\dimen137
> \Fld@menulength=\count184
> \Field@Width=\dimen138
> \Fld@charsize=\dimen139
> Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 6380.
> Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 6385.
> Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 6388.
> Package hyperref Info: backreferencing OFF on input line 6395.
> Package hyperref Info: Link coloring OFF on input line 6400.
> Package hyperref Info: Link coloring with OCG OFF on input line 6405.
> Package hyperref Info: PDF/A mode OFF on input line 6410.
> LaTeX Info: Redefining \ref on input line 6450.
> LaTeX Info: Redefining \pageref on input line 6454.
> \Hy@abspage=\count185
> \c@Item=\count186
> \c@Hfootnote=\count187
> )
> Package hyperref Info: Driver (autodetected): hpdftex.
>
> (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hpdftex.def
> File: hpdftex.def 2018/11/30 v6.88e Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
> \Fld@listcount=\count188
> \c@bookmark@seq@number=\count189
>
> (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/rerunfilecheck.sty
> Package: rerunfilecheck 2016/05/16 v1.8 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
> Package uniquecounter Info: New unique counter `rerunfilecheck' on input line 2
> 82.
> )
> \Hy@SectionHShift=\skip49
> )
> (./Untitled.aux)
> \openout1 = `Untitled.aux'.
>
> LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 30.
> LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 30.
> LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 30.
> LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 30.
> LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 30.
> LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 30.
> LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 30.
> LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 30.
> LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 30.
> LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 30.
> LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 30.
> LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 30.
> LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for PD1/pdf/m/n on input line 30.
> LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 30.
> \AtBeginShipoutBox=\box46
> Package hyperref Info: Link coloring OFF on input line 30.
>
> (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
> Package: nameref 2016/05/21 v2.44 Cross-referencing by name of section
>
> (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/gettitlestring.sty
> Package: gettitlestring 2016/05/16 v1.5 Cleanup title references (HO)
> )
> \c@section@level=\count190
> )
> LaTeX Info: Redefining \ref on input line 30.
> LaTeX Info: Redefining \pageref on input line 30.
> LaTeX Info: Redefining \nameref on input line 30.
>
> (./Untitled.out) (./Untitled.out)
> \@outlinefile=\write3
> \openout3 = `Untitled.out'.
>
>  (./Untitled.toc)
> \tf@toc=\write4
> \openout4 = `Untitled.toc'.
>
>  [1
>
>
> {/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
> [2
>
> ]
> Chapter 1.
> [3] [4] [5] [6] [7] [8
>
> ]
> Chapter 2.
> [9] [10
>
> ]
> Chapter 3.
> Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `BeforeClearDocument' on input line 44.
> [11]
> Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `AfterLastShipout' on input line 44.
>  (./Untitled.aux)
> Package atveryend Info: Executing hook `AtVeryEndDocument' on input line 44.
> Package atveryend Info: Executing hook `AtEndAfterFileList' on input line 44.
> Package rerunfilecheck Info: File `Untitled.out' has not changed.
> (rerunfilecheck)             Checksum: EFA5D490BF925B77535D7D7DA27CE7E0;461.
> Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `AtVeryVeryEnd' on input line 44.
>  ) 
> Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
>  14100 strings out of 492616
>  259219 string characters out of 6129480
>  571398 words of memory out of 5000000
>  17991 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
>  536327 words of font info for 37 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
>  1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
>  40i,5n,63p,227b,351s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
> </usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx10.pfb
> ></usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx12.pfb>
> </usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx9.pfb></
> usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb></us
> r/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr8.pfb></usr/l
> ocal/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr9.pfb></usr/loca
> l/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmsl10.pfb>
> Output written on Untitled.pdf (11 pages, 89265 bytes).
> PDF statistics:
>  144 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
>  113 compressed objects within 2 object streams
>  22 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
>  73 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
> ```

Comment: Works fine for me. If I remember correctly Javier changed something in titletoc to avoid the problem. Is your titletoc version up-to-date?

Comment: To add to what @Ulrike wrote: see [this bug report on titlesec](https://github.com/jbezos/titlesec/issues/3).

Comment: @WillieWong I tried redefining with `\gdef` but nothing changed. I'm trying to do the update as @Ulrike Fischer suggests and then report back...

Comment: @GiuTeX Sorry it wasn't clear: I didn't intend for you to try to fix the def yourself. The link I sent was to document what Ulrike wrote. An update was pushed to titletoc on Feb 26 that works around this problem, so updating should work.

Comment: I updated MacTeX to 2019 version but nothing seems to change...

Comment: Show your log file.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer added, I see now there is written `LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>` but I can not understand how, since I do not have anymore the 2018 distribution. Anyway `titletoc.sty` is from 2019, so it should change...

Comment: that is not the log-file but the terminal output. And so it doesn't contain version info. But your latex is clearly older as mine (LaTeX2e <2019-10-01> patch level 3), so I doubt that you updated your tex system.

Comment: Should be right now, sorry.

Comment: Your titletoc version: titletoc 2011/12/15 v1.6 TOC entries, mine: titletoc 2019/10/16 v2.13 TOC entries.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102203/discussion-between-giutex-and-ulrike-fischer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to the problem was (as suggested by Ulrike Fisher) just to update the [`titletoc.sty`](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titletoc.sty) to the earliest version (2019) since in previous versions it seems there was [this bug adjusted by Bezos](https://github.com/jbezos/titlesec/issues/3) in February.

I add a brief guide to the update of the sole package on Mac OS since in reinstalling the whole MacTeX distribution I did not get the newer version of the package (thanks to Ulrike Fisher who made me note this).
By using the shell command line `locate` the path where `titletoc.sty` is installed on the Mac

```
$ locate titletoc.sty
%should give /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/titlesec/titletoc.sty
```

then download the updated version of the package from [here (on CTAN)](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec) and substitute it directly inside the folder.
This fixed the problem.

Comment: Good to see it fixed! My workaround back in 2014, was to load `hyperref` in steps: begin TOC definitions with `linktoc=none`, and near the end turn the `linktoc=page` switch on. If you're interested, you'd find the detailed answer in my original question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/162846/how-to-imitate-great-looking-motion-mountain-toc-including-hyperlinks).